# Keras - Unexpected prediction results

Tags: keras, lstm, predict

I'm trying to create a `keras` LSTM to predict time series. My x_train is shaped like 3000,15,10 (Examples, Timesteps, Features), y_train like 3000,15,1 and I'm trying to build a many to many model (10 input features per sequence make 1 output / sequence).

The code I'm using is this:

```python
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(
    10,
    input_shape=(15, 10),
    return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(
    100,
    return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="rmsprop")
model.fit(
        x_train, y_train,
        batch_size=1, nb_epoch=1, validation_split=0.05)
predicted = model.predict(x_test)
```

My data looks like this:

```python
x_train = [
    [
        [3,4,3,1.5,0,7....], # 10 Features
        [2,4,1,1,4,3....],
        .... # 15 Timesteps
    ],
    .... # 3000 Examples
]
y_train = [
    [
        [0],
        [5],
        ....
    ],
    .....
]
```

The code compiles and fits without errors but the predicted values are not realistic.

The expected values are integers between 0 and ~15. However, the predictions are floats between ~-0.03 and 1. Also, the predictions have 15 timesteps but I am actually interested in the 16th timestep (predicted future result).

Example predictions:

```python
predicted = [
    [
        [0.035478],
        [0.046423],
        [0.948723],
        ....
    ],
    ....
]
```

My Keras version is 2.0.6 and Python is version 3.4.5.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably rescale your y_train to be between 0 and 1.  Assuming y_train and predicted are numpy arrays:

```
y_train = y_train/15.0
```

Then you can rescale your predictions when you are done.

```
predicted = (predicted*15).astype(int)
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, I will try this. Do you have any idea how to retrieve the 16th prediction?

Comment: Since you're doing your prediction on x_test,  make sure x_test has your 16th timestep in it.

Comment: Thank you, I scaled the data to be between 0 and 1 and now all results seem a lot more realistic. I also thought it over and I will be sticking with just 15 timesteps but shift my inputs and results by cutting off the last input timestep and inserting an empty one in the beginning. Therefore every x value corresponds to the next y value. However, the results still are not correct, as I am mostly receiving the same number (~0.018) for all results. Do you know what's up with that?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to build a many to many model (10 input features per sequence make 1 output / sequence).

Seems to me that you want to build a many to one model. (10 input features for 1 output per sequence)

For this you need to:

1. Build y_train with shape (3000,1). y_train will be the future prediction, the prediction on t+1 time. If you want to predict for more time steps adjust your y_train and your last dense layer to do so.
2. If you haven't already, scale your training data as neural networks need scale data.
3. Remove return_sequences from your last LSTM layer like this:

code

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(15, 10), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but I actually thought it over and I really need a many to many model, I think. Its basically necessary to predict every next result of all my timesteps. What is the reason to change the `return_sequence`?